# Lazy evaluation in Ruby

Tags: ruby, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

I have a situation for Ruby, where an object is possibly necessary to be created, but it is not sure. And as the creation of the object might be costly I am not too eager creating it. I think this is a clear case for lazy loading. How can I define an object which is not created only when someone sends a message to it? The object would be created in a block. Is there a way for simple lazy loading/initialisation in Ruby? Are these things supported by some gems, which provide different solutions for various cases of lazy initialisation of objects? Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 41):

There are two ways.

The first is to let the **caller** handle lazy object creation. This is the simplest solution, and it is a **very common pattern** in Ruby code.

```
class ExpensiveObject
  def initialize
    # Expensive stuff here.
  end
end

class Caller
  def some_method
    my_object.do_something
  end

  def my_object
    # Expensive object is created when my_object is called. Subsequent calls
    # will return the same object.
    @my_object ||= ExpensiveObject.new
  end
end
```

The second option is to let the **object** initialise itself lazily. We create a delegate object around our actual object to achieve this. This approach is a little more tricky and not recommended unless you have existing calling code that you can't modify, for example.

```
class ExpensiveObject        # Delegate
  class RealExpensiveObject  # Actual object
    def initialize
      # Expensive stuff here.
    end

    # More methods...
  end

  def initialize(*args)
    @init_args = args
  end

  def method_missing(method, *args)
    # Delegate to expensive object. __object method will create the expensive
    # object if necessary.
    __object__.send(method, *args)
  end

  def __object__
    @object ||= RealExpensiveObject.new(*@init_args)
  end
end

# This will only create the wrapper object (cheap).
obj = ExpensiveObject.new

# Only when the first message is sent will the internal object be initialised.
obj.do_something
```

You could also use the stdlib [`delegate`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/index.html) to build this on top of.

Comment: In the first example I need to keep instance of Caller class. Right? But what is the difference for me - to keep Caller class instance or to keep Expensive class instance?

Comment: In the first example, the `Caller` class is just an example of how you would *use* the ExpensiveObject class. The difference: introduce laziness where you *use* the `ExpensiveObject` (simple), or introduce laziness in the `ExpensiveObject` *itself* (slightly more complicated).

Comment: @molf: Whenever you override `method_missing` you *must* also override `respond_to?` (or preferably `respond_to_missing?` in 1.9.2).  See http://blog.marc-andre.ca/2010/11/methodmissing-politely.html

Answer (score 7):

If you want to lazily evaluate pieces of code, use a proxy:

```
class LazyProxy

  # blank slate... (use BasicObject in Ruby 1.9)
  instance_methods.each do |method| 
    undef_method(method) unless method =~ /^__/
  end

  def initialize(&lazy_proxy_block)
    @lazy_proxy_block = lazy_proxy_block
  end

  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    @lazy_proxy_obj ||= @lazy_proxy_block.call # evaluate the real receiver
    @lazy_proxy_obj.send(method, *args, &block) # delegate unknown methods to the real receiver
  end
end
```

You then use it like this:

```
expensive_object = LazyProxy.new { ExpensiveObject.new }
expensive_object.do_something
```

You can use this code to do arbitrarily complex initialization of expensive stuff:

```
expensive_object = LazyProxy.new do
  expensive_helper = ExpensiveHelper.new
  do_really_expensive_stuff_with(expensive_helper)
  ExpensiveObject.new(:using => expensive_helper)
end
expensive_object.do_something
```

How does it work? You instantiate a LazyProxy object that holds instructions on how to build some expensive object in a Proc. If you then call some method on the proxy object, it first instantiates the expensive object and then delegates the method call to it.

Answer (score 0):

With Ruby 3.x, I use the gem `concurrent-ruby`.
A possible lazy initialization use case looks as following:

```
require 'concurrent'

# put expensive code inside a "future":
very_lazy = Concurrent::Promises.future { some_expensive_code_block }
# the "future" starts performing work in background

# use
puts very_lazy.value   # blocks, until the "future" is ready
puts very_lazy.value   # repeated calls just re-use existing value
```

*If I'm wrong, someone please correct me.*