# adding a method to application_controller so it is visible to all controllers and views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a method that will be available in all controllers, and views.

This method actually makes a db call to get data back, so since it won't be used all the time I want it be be lazily loaded.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base


  def some_method
    @object = customdb.call_method(....)
  end

end
```

To make it lazily loaded do I just do?

```
@object ||= ....
```

And how do I propagate this to all controllers and view pages?

Answer (score 5):

Use **[helper_method](http://ruby.robu.se/posts/4-helper_method-to-the-rescue)** in *ApplicationController* to make some_method available in any controller or view:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :some_method

  def some_method
    @object ||= customdb.call_method(....)
  end
end
```

The ||= does per request caching, not lazy loading. Lazy loading is the [deferred initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461432/lazy-evaluation-in-ruby) pattern.

Big scopes and controller methods in views are code smells. Best to minimize object scope and view logic.

Comment: This will not make the result accessible across requests. The result is cached during one request.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `memoize` feature provided by `ActiveSupport`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Memoizable.html

http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/7/16/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-memoization

So possibly something like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def some_method
    @object = customdb.call_method(....)
  end

  memoize :some_method

end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result to be accessible across accross requests, you have to store the results in a class variable:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :city_list

  def city_list
    @@city_list =|| City.order(:name)
  end
end
```

The result is lazy loaded and cached.
PS: The variable `@@city_list` is a class variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `before_filter`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :some_method

  def some_method
    @object = customdb.call_method(....)
  end

end
```

It will be triggered in all your controllers.

Note that you can skip this before filter using `skip_before_filter :some_method` wherever you want. You can even prevent only some actions to be preceded by this filter.

Because this will be triggered before all decided controller actions, you won't need your line:

```
@object ||= ....
```

Since `@object`  will be instantiated.

Comment: but does this give me lazy loading?

Comment: that's the principle of Rails 3: lazy loading in controller. Queries made once needed in views.

Comment: just FYI, you force loading in controller when you use `all`, `first` & `last`